# Why do floated elements appear before non floated element, even if they come after it in the markup?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I thought that text will flow around a floated element if the text follows that element in the markup. Why then does the following example produce the shown result?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="float block red">Red</div>
TEXT BETWEEN RED AND BLUE
<div class="float block blue">Blue</div>
<div class="float block green">Green</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.float{
    float: left;
}
.block{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.red{ background-color: red;  }
.blue{ background-color: blue; }
.green{ background-color: green; }
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

Why isn't the order on screen: Red, TEXT BETWEEN RED AND BLUE, Blue, Green?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> “A floated box is positioned within the normal flow, then taken out of the flow and shifted to the left or right as far as possible. Content may flow along the side of a float. [...] When a box is taken out of normal flow, all content that is still within normal flow will ignore it completely and not make space for it.”

[Source](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/definitions.htm)

It's because you're floating the elements left. You're essentially saying that those elements will be as far left on the page as they can be, relative to other floated elements. Your text is not floated, and is thus relative to the right-most, left-floated element. Does that make sense?

To achieve your desired result, just put the text in a DIV, SPAN, etc. and float it left also.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of elements in CSS: Block level and Inline elements.  These elements, and their positioning, are governed by a concept known as the flow.

Block-level elements have breaks before and after them, inline elements do not.  While this is extremely over-simplified, these are the basic rules that govern flow in CSS.

Elements that are given `position:fixed` and elements that are given a `float` attribute *are removed from the flow in the normal sense*, with the additional caveat that inline elements and text will wrap around the floated element.

If you can imagine a floated element as a box that physically lifts itself off the ground, flies to the left or the right until it can go no further, and then plops itself back down on the ground, you've got the right idea (think Terran bases in StarCraft).  The floated element blows right by your text, and then your text repositions itself to wrap around the floated stuff once it has "landed".

Floats always position themselves in relative to other floats.

The exception to this is when an element has a `clear` stuck to it. The CSS clear property basically says that any block level element will either permit floats to be on one or the other side, else kick the floated element down to the next line.  It's actually a little more complicated than that, you should check out the [MDN article on Clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear).